# jQuery selecting dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have dynamically created forms in my page. So once a checkbox in that form checked I want to post the form using jQuery. I still can't select the form correctly.

HTML code:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <form id="" class="recmndation">
            <td>sdfdsfdsfdsfsdfsdfsdfsd</td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Luxury Resorts" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Honeymoon Resorts" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Dive Resorts" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Surf Resorts" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Spa Resorts" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Over-night Resorts" />
            </td>
            <input type="hidden" name="hotel_id" value="2" />
        </form>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <form id="" class="recmndation">
            <td>tests</td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Luxury Resorts" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Honeymoon Resorts" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Dive Resorts" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Surf Resorts" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Spa Resorts" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Over-night Resorts" />
            </td>
            <input type="hidden" name="hotel_id" value="1" />
        </form>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

jQuery code:

```
<script>
    $('.checkboxes').on('change', function() {
        var val = $(this).parents('.recmndation').attr('id');
        alert(val);
    });
</script>
```

The `alert` message always says "undefined" and there are no errors in the console.

PHP code:

```
<?php
if (!empty($hotel_list)) {
    foreach ($hotel_list as $htls) {
        ?>
        <tr>
        <form id="<?php $htls->name ?>" class="recmndation">
        <td><?php echo $htls->name; ?></td>
        <?php
        if ($rcmnd_list) {
            foreach ($rcmnd_list as $rcl) {
                ?>
                <td><input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $rcl->rec_name; ?>" /></td>
                <?php
            }
        }
        ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="hotel_id" value="<?php echo $htls->hotel_id; ?>" />
        </form>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you share the generated html

Comment: Could you update the rendered HTML instead of PHP?

Comment: Your html is invalid because `tr` can't have a `form` as a child

Comment: what about :``$(this).closest('.recmndation')``

Comment: have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/otk7tqfu/1/) inspect the html and you can see how the form element is created

Comment: your id="" values are empty ..that code is working fine if id has some value  http://jsfiddle.net/e8a5e8hz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try this and it should work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.checkboxes').on('change', function() {
        var val = $(this).closest('.recmndation').attr('id');
                 OR YOU CAN USE PROP
        var val = $(this).closest('.recmndation').prop('id');
        alert(val);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I see.. The html is invalid and if it is corrected then the above mentioned script will work proper. :)

Comment: @Yasitha, are you sure this solution is working? I am testing in my machine and it doesn't :-(


When I mix form with table like the code what's mentioned above, It's not working.

Comment: @Rajacsp - Yes It is working. and also I change my html coding. now I put a full table inside the form tags.

Comment: Great.. Cheers.. @Rajacsp you need to create another question for your html if its not working. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all,

1) your form id is empty! so, you will get only empty in alert.

Second of all,

2) please provide `<table>` inside `<form>` not the other way around.

Your code format should be like this:

```
    <form id="two" class="recmndation">

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <td><input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Luxury Resorts" /></td>
                <td><input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Honeymoon Resorts" /></td>
                <td><input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Dive Resorts" /></td>
                <td><input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Surf Resorts" /></td>
                <td><input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Spa Resorts" /></td>
                <td><input class="checkboxes" type="checkbox" name="Over-night Resorts" /></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="hotel_id" value="1" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>



    <script>
        $('.checkboxes').on('change', function() {
            var val = $(this).parents('.recmndation').attr('id');
            alert(val);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Raja csp : This is not an answer so you must add this as a comment and not an answer. Secondly read the question properly. The form ID is `id="<?php $htls->name ?>"` ..

Comment: @Yunus just look rendered html <form id="" class="recmndation">